# How to categorize typography variants in BEM?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have just recently been introduced to BEM and I'm excited to implement the methodology in my react component library.

I have a Typography component with different variants. Notably, the variant is required (i.e. there is no default).

Suppose I have these variants:

- header1
- header2
- header3

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement BEM for this typography component.
One option would be to make each variant its own block element like so:

```css
.header1 {}

.header2 {}

.header3 {}
```

However, these are technically variants or modifiers, aren't they?
So another option is to make each variant a modifier like so:

```
.typography {
  &--header1 {}  

  &--header2 {}  

  &--header3 {}  
}
```

But block element `typography` is supposed to be able to stand-alone. In this case, the variants are required...
The more I think about this, the more unsure I feel about how to best name this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The second option is more in-line with the BEM philosophy, i.e:

```scss
.typography {
  &--header1 {}  

  &--header2 {}  

  &--header3 {}  
}
```

The "one class per component" principle is a good rule of thumb in general.